# Why do I get this error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Serializable to T"?

Tags: java, generics, serialization, casting

With the the following code:

**Main.java**

```
 // ...

 private static <T extends Serializable> T doStuff() {
     Response r = ...

     // ...

     return r.getDetails();//Error here
 }

 // ...
```

**Response.java**

```
 interface Response {
    // ...

    Serializable getDetails();

    // ...
 }
```

I get this compile error : "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Serializable to T" in the `doStuff` method.

If I cast the returned result , the error is removed.

```
  return (T)r.getDetails();
```

But now I have this warning : `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Serializable to T`.
`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` would suppress the warning but I find this solution ugly.

Is there any better option ?

Comment: Return type is T not Serializable, that's the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the getDetails() will always return T when you call it in doStuff()? If it is yes, or you've done type checking, then you can suppress the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you give too little implementation details I would suggest to make `Response` generic:

```
private static <T extends Serializable> T doStuff() {
    Response<T> r = ...;

// ...

    return r.getDetails();
}

interface Response<T extends Serializable> {
    // ...

    T getDetails();

    // ...
}
```

But that won't necessary work with the rest of the thing you might have. The problem is what Thorsten Dittmar already wrote.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that by your code, every `T` must be a `Serializable`, but not every `Serializable` is also a `T`.

Assuming that both `T1` and `T2` were `Serializable`, the following would also cause problems:

```
T1 t = new T2();
```

as `T1` and `T2` are not related, even though they are both `Serializable`.

Comment: For more information on this, you might want to check out the Wikipedia page on [Covariance and Contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast your returned Object to `T` type
like this:

```
return (T) r.getDetails();
```

**UPDATE**

Then you have to make your `Response` interface or `getDetails()` method generic.
like this:

```
interface Response<T extends Serializable> {
// ...

T getDetails();

}
```

or

```
interface Response {
// ...

<T extends Serializable> T getDetails();

}
```

Comment: I have posted my answer before alex extended her question.

Answer (score 0):

All of following compiles w/o warnings and should give you an idea:

```
interface Response<T extends Serializable> {
    T getResponse();
}


class Sample {
    private static <T extends Serializable> T get(Response<T> generator) {
        return generator.getResponse();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(get(new Response<Serializable>() {
            @Override
            public String getResponse() {
                return "string";
            }
        }));
        System.out.println(get(new Response<Serializable>() {
            @Override
            public Integer getResponse() {
                return 1;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```